# Поиска в бинарном файле по маске

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, search, hex

Есть бинарный файл. В нём нужно найти последовательности байтов по маске:

`XX XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 ZZ ZZ .. ZZ 00 00`.

Под XX и ZZ понимаются любые значения байтов, байтов в последовательности XX (перед `00 00 00 00`) всегда четыре. Байтов ZZ (перед `00 00`) неизвестное число. В исследуемом файле таких последовательностей может быть очень много (около 1000). Сам файл по размеру ~85 килобайт.

Задача стоит в том, что бы написать программку, которая будет выдирать эти последовательности из файла. Можно, в принципе, использовать готовые решения, но я не нашёл HEX-редакторов, которые будут искать по маске.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм/функции/библиотеки/готовые решения, с помощью которых можно решить мою задачу.

Comment: Судя по меткам, вы знаете С/С++. Что именно вызывает сложности в задаче? Открываете файл, читаете его по байтам, проверяете послдеовательности, сохраняете что нужно в другой файл.

Comment: Для таких мелких файлов всегда можно преобразовать их в текст и искать обычными регулярками. Это немножко не эффективно, но скорее всего хватит с головой

Comment: В видеокодеках есть такая задача. Если не ошибаюсь - есть три решения такой проблемы: 1) буфер со сдвигом 2) циклический буфер.  В любом случае размер буфера должен быть >= длинна маски. 3) вычитать весь кусок в память и проанализировать. (85к для современных систем, это не много). Возможно последнее само проще.

Comment: На счёт маски - так и напишите   `if (( a[i] == 0) && (a[i+1] == 0)) ..` и нужную маску заложите.

Comment: А что именно вы хотите реализовать?  Может это уже реализовано?

Comment: Что такое у вас `..` ? Маска переменная? Вот имеенно `..` вносит в задачу непонятки, маска - означает что каждый байт находится на своём месте, а если у вас переменное число байт - то это уже не маска, а комбинация масок, то ваша задача сразу же переходит в разряд сложных, где ответ может стать "комбинаторным" и в отдельных случаях превращаться в длинные циклы ( 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9 = безконечность).

Comment: У меня есть исполняемый файл, в котором зашифрованы строки. Я нашёл алгоритм расшифровки и реализовал его на C++. Сейчас я хочу расшифровать все строки. Я сделал дамп секции, в которой находятся зашифрованные строки. XX XX XX XX - ключ для расшифровки, далее идут 4 нулевых байта и сама зашифрованная строка, длина которой неизвестна. Известно только то, что она заканчивается двумя нулевыми байтами

Comment: Так используйте обычное сравнение в цикле для поиска 4-х байт (если вас смущает длинное условие - есть ф-ция сравнения в памяти [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) ). А на счёт двух последних - возьмите ф-цию работы со строками unicode, допустим  [wcscpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscpy/)

Comment: Можете адаптировать под вашу задачу функцию [strstr](https://github.com/wuzhouhui/c_standard_lib/blob/master/STRING/STRSTR.C). Нужно будет добавить проверку длины массива вместо поиска нуль-терминатора.

Comment: @nick_n_a, то есть, Вы предлагаете такой алгоритм: читаю из файла 4 байта, с помощью memcpy проверяю, что эти 4 байта - нулевые. Если это так, то пытаюсь получить 4 байта перед этими нулевыми. Если получилось, то беру байты за этими 4мя нулевыми байтами, пока не найду 00 00. Таким образом получаю зашифрованную 
строку. Верное?